Why should we help anyone?
I am a bit newbie here, so please take it easy.
Suppose a person is in trouble. So, should we help him to get out his trouble or not?
According to any ancient text or any scripture, we should help.
But, When we think about the backstory that why would a person be in trouble in the first place? Then one thing comes to my mind that is result of his own karma. Any person would be in trouble (whether it is mentally, physically, economically, or anything), it is the result of his own karma.
So, thinking that, it makes sense that we should not help anyone as that person is in problem due to his own karma. If we help that person, then we are preventing that person to suffer the results of his karma. So, in that person's perspective, even if he did wrong, and we saved him from his karma, then he would think that there is no effect of karma, so he would continue doing wrong things, and next time a third person would save him from the results of his karma and the cycle of doing wrong things will never end.
Then why every ancient text, scriptures and even every religon says that we should help everyone?
Am I missing something in this whole senerio?

All are One. When you help someone else you are helping yourself. See others as God. If you see yourself as separate, you are identifying yourself with your material body...

Don't you want to get good karma?

@Vatapatrashaayi I want. But the point is that by helping someone, won't I be praising that person in doing wrong things? Suppose someone lies to you, and I also help him and lie, so I would be somewhat equal paapi. Just like that, someone has done wrong and I am helping him, so I would be equal paapi in doing that wrong thing.

@VanshPatel are you referring to Apatra Dhanam?

@Vatapatrashaayi Not exactly. But you can say that. My question is wouldn't helping anyone should be considered a sin? If you talk in terms of Apatra Dhanam, then you can say that everyone is unworthy of any help.

Firstly, in the scriptures, people help others only when they ask for it. If someone comes to you for help, it is up to you to help or not. This can be understood from the words of Shunasepa to Vishwamitra in Valmiki Ramayana

त्वं मे नाथो ह्यनाथस्य भव भव्येन चेतसा |
पितेव पुत्रं धर्मात्मन्स्त्रातुमर्हसि किल्बिषात् ||1.62.7

Secondly, asking someone for help is a destruction of your own pride. So someone helping you out is not a great thing either. In fact, relying on others for help is considered a great misfortune in itself. This destruction of pride is the fruit of your Karma. This can be understood from the words of a Brahmani in the 173rd Adhyaya, Bakavadhaparva, Mahabharata (Southern Recension)

किं त्वतः परमं दुखं यद्वयं स्वर्गते त्वयि || 16
याचमानाः पराअदन्नम् परिधावेमहि श्ववत् |

Thirdly, someone being able to help and alleviate someone's problem is an increment in the fame and name of the person. You get a chance to be equivalent to God Himself for someone in need. If you read the scripture, the person who seeks someone's help calls the able person with Divine Honorific. This can be understood again from the 175th Adhyaya, Bakavadhaparva where Bhima is worshipped by the family when He decides to go face Bakasura instead

एवमुक्तस्तु पृथया स विप्रो भार्यया सह |
हृष्टः सम्पूजयमास तद्वाक्यममृतोपमम् || 19

And finally let me add that there are four kinds of ऋण or debts. Pitra, Deva, Rishi and Manushya, helping others help you get out of the Manushya debt.

You don't help for their sake, even though that is the motive. You help others for your own sake, i.e. to accumulate good karma for yourself. Especially so if you have hurt or injured others previously, since good karma now would reduce such negative karma so you wouldn't have to pay for all of it in the future.
Moreover, in Bhagavad Gita God gives a similar reason as to why charity should not be abandoned but performed:
18th sarga, verse 5 -

यज्ञदानतप:कर्म न त्याज्यं कार्यमेव तत् |यज्ञो दानं तपश्चैव पावनानि मनीषिणाम् || 5||


yajña-dāna-tapaḥ-karma na tyājyaṁ kāryam eva tat
yajño dānaṁ tapaśh chaiva pāvanāni manīṣhiṇām

Actions based upon sacrifice, charity (same as help - charity of your time & energy) and penance should never be abandoned; they must certainly be performed. Indeed, acts of sacrifice, charity, and penance are purifiers of the wise.
Also in the 17th sarga verse 20 in Bhagavad Gita God says:

दातव्यमिति यद्दानं दीयतेऽनुपकारिणे |
देशे काले च पात्रे च तद्दानं सात्त्विकं स्मृतम् || 20||


dātavyam iti yad dānaṁ dīyate ‘nupakāriṇe
deśhe kāle cha pātre cha tad dānaṁ sāttvikaṁ smṛitam

Charity (of your time & energy to someone) given to a worthy person simply because it is right to give, without consideration of anything in return, at the proper time and in the proper place, is stated to be sattvik (established in the highest quality of mind and conduct).
